# Sitecore 8.2 MVC can't get MVC bundles to work

Tags: model-view-controller, sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8.2

I have been trying to set up Sitecore 8.2 MVC and use the MVC bundle to pull all my scripts and styles on to the main layout. I have been running into issues since the global file is no longer being used and best practices I should be initializing the buldler using the pipeline.

BundleConfig.cs

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Pipelines;

namespace MySite.Web.Pipelines
{

    public class RegisterPlatformBundles
    {
        [UsedImplicitly]
        public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
        {
            RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
        private void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/styles").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));

        }

    }
```

I tried to add it to the pipeline withthe following config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeGlobalFilters, Sitecore.Mvc']"
           type="MySite.Web.Pipelines.RegisterPlatformBundles, MySite" />
      </initialize>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

I get the following error when I try to run the site. Any advice or even just the right path to help me set this up would be great. Thanks.

> Could not resolve type name:
>   MySite.Web.Pipelines.RegisterPlatformBundles, MySite (method:
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)). Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Exception: Could not resolve type name:
>   MySite.Web.Pipelines.RegisterPlatformBundles, MySite (method:
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [Exception: Could not resolve type name:
>   MySite.Web.Pipelines.RegisterPlatformBundles, MySite (method:
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).]
>   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Error.Raise(String error, String method) +137
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateType(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +308
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +71
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +165
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   Boolean assert) +68
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetObjectFromType(XmlNode
>   processorNode) +91
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetProcessorObject(XmlNode
>   processorNode) +145
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CoreProcessor.GetMethod(Object[] parameters) +144
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +470
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +262
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +704
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +618
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +402
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +343
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not resolve type name:
>   MySite.Web.Pipelines.RegisterPlatformBundles, MySite (method:
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +539
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +125    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +731

Comment: Please refer this [LINK](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3434/is-there-something-in-sitecore-8-2-that-breaks-bundling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the provided code and the main reason why you are receiving this error is because the assembly `Mysite` is not present in the bin folder.

1. Make sure that the `MySite.dll` is copied to the bin folder.
2. Namespace `MySite.Web.Pipelines.RegisterPlatformBundles, MySite` is valid

Comment: Thanks, that's what I kind of thought. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything. This kind of confirmed it. I ended up find out what was actually causing it. My Project had a space in the name, so the assembly ended up having a space in some places and an underscore in others. I removed all reference to the space and underscore. Then it was able to find my assembly.